# How can I compress a file into .rar using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, compression, rar

I have a file named `mytext.txt` and I'd like to compress this file to `archive.rar`. How can I do this in `nodejs`?

I've found nothing similar to `rar` only `zip`.

Answer (score 2):

Find an rar command line utility that you can execute like

```
$ rar myfile.dat compressed.rar
```

Node.js can do command line calls. (See `child_process.exec`)

Give the normal command to the exec function, and it should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

For zipping a single file, *zlib* module can be very useful.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  var zlib = require('zlib');
  var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
  var fs = require('fs');
  var inp = fs.createReadStream('mytext.txt');
  var out = fs.createWriteStream('mytext.txt.gz');

  inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Nodejs dosn't native support Rar compression/decompression, i frustated with this too so i created a module called "super-winrar" making super easy deal with rar files in nodejs :)

check it out: https://github.com/KiyotakaAyanokojiDev/super-winrar

Exemple creating a file "archive.rar" and appending "mytext.txt" file:

```
const Rar = require('super-winrar');

// create a rar constructor with file path! (created if not exists)
const rar = new Rar('archive.rar');

// handle erros, otherwise will throw an exception!
rar.on('error', err => console.log(err.message));

rar.once('ready', async () => {
  await rar.append(['mytext.txt']);
});
```